# Algorithms for Motion Detection in python with opencv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-vision, motion-detection

I have been finding out about Motion Detection algorithm for very long but unable to decide which algorithm will give me best performance.
I am uisng a IP camera to capture video stream using opencv and further like to detect Motion(Human motion actually) 
can any one suggest me which algorithm which will give me best performance in any lighting environment.

Comment: You could include what algorithms you have been finding out about, and what your findings were for each of those.

Comment: what about background subtraction : First extract the background (http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html) , then subtract every frame from that background.

Comment: Have a look at this page. https://github.com/lohithpro/intruder_detector_capture_alarm